# ASP.NET MVC - how to set the dataValueField of a SelectList when binding to a List<string>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What do I use to set the `dataValueField` of the `SelectList` when I'm using a `List<string>`. I want to be able to set the value of the option in the select.  If I have:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("apple");
list.Add("orange");
```

and I want my html to be:

```
<select>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly each item is a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using the `DataValueField`. You can create your own class which wraps your list for your drop down:

```
public class ListWrapper
{
    private List<string> _list;

    public ListWrapper(List<string> list)
    {
        this._list = list;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(" ", _list.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: how would the Html.DropDownList syntax look like?

Comment: seems easier just to use a Dictionary<string,string> and use Key,Value to set the properties

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the question, can you place the items in the drop down and the list coming in?